# Is there a word for the opposite side of 'tip'?

Tags: word-usage

I would like to write something like 'A marker is mounted on the tail of the surgical instrument'. Is 'tail' a formal word to describe the other side of 'tip'? It sounds kind of informal to me and I'm looking for a formal word. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think it depends on the shape of the object. Instinctively, I think of "base" as the opposite of "tip" - but not all shapes that have a tip also have a base opposite it.

Comment: Could you specify what kind of a medical instrument you are referring to?

Comment: Olease post a pic of it as it really depends on the shape of the item. You could say anterior or anterior side or offside but it really depends.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a medic so you need to double-check but I believe the correct technical term is the "shank"

https://www.teleflex.com/en/usa/pdf/KMedic_Surgical_Instruments_101.pdf

Note that your use of 'tip' is probably incorrect - it depends on the type of instrument.

Here is a diagram for one type of instrument:
[image]

http://img.medicalexpo.com/images_me/photo-g/116752-11100551.jpg

Comment: Haft is another option for shank, I think.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to EL&U!

According to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tip), a tip (in the sense described in the question) is

> 1 : the usually pointed end of something
>   [as in] *a pencil tip*
>
> 2 : a small piece or part serving as an end, cap, or point

Note that it states in neither definition *which* end of the object it is, simply that it is one.

Following this trail of thought we may make the following sentence:

> Thread the thread through the *tip of the needle with the eye*, then use the *opposing tip* of the needle to penetrate the fabric, pulling the thread through with it.

In a similar fashion you could have, assuming the surgical instrument is a scalpel

> A marker is mounted on **the tip opposite to the blade** of the surgical instrument.

Therefore you may continue to use tip.

---

Tail does not necessarily mean the rear end of e.g. an instrument, but may be

> 9. the back, last, lower, or inferior part of something

(again from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tail)), which is the closest definition I could find.

As long as your instrument has a definite rear end you may also use tail, as in your proposed sentence.